# Angular Material Dialog Closing restrict

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way to restrict closing of Angular Material Dialog on any click on the body ?

I am using Angular Material with Angular 4 for my project. I need to find a way to this.

Comment: There is a `disableClose` option: https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using 'disableClose' property.